# Depth / Perspective with CoreImage?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ios6, core-image

I would like to create an effect like the image below using **one single CALayer** - not by splitting the image, performing perspective transformation on both halves and then placing next to each other.

Can this be done in any way using CoreImage? 
Alternatively, can someone point me in the right direction using OpenGL?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. Split Image
2. Perform perspective on each side
3. Create context and concatenate.
4. Finish context and set image to your layer.